# SQLite BUSY on commit callback

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.7

The idea is to make backup of a database by calling trace callback. But in some reason sqlite is busy on commit (code 5 - status arg in __progress func). The doc says about backup method.

> "This method makes a backup of a SQLite database even while it’s being
> accessed by other clients, or concurrently by the same connection"

```
import sqlite3


db_name = "main.db"
init_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS app_states (\
sync_state_id INTEGER NOT NULL);\
INSERT INTO app_states (sync_state_id) VALUES (1)"

conn1 = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
conn1.executescript(init_sql)
conn2 = sqlite3.connect(db_name+".temp")
in_memory_db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

conn1.backup(in_memory_db)

def __progress(status, remaining, total):
    print(status, remaining, total)

def backup_callback(s):
    print(s)
    if ("commit" in s.lower()):
        in_memory_db.backup(conn2, pages=1, progress=__progress)

in_memory_db.set_trace_callback(backup_callback)

in_memory_db.execute(f"BEGIN TRANSACTION")
in_memory_db.execute("UPDATE app_states SET sync_state_id=2")
in_memory_db.execute("COMMIT")

conn1.close()
conn2.close()
in_memory_db.close()
```

Comment: Interesting question. Method `backup` uses [SQLite online backup API](https://sqlite.org/backup.html) under the hood. It's understood, however not documented, that you can't perform backup within a active write-transaction. Thatcan be verified in [SQLite source code](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/0cb735b9fbc76f8f14798f48c166f1b31ab8a9dd/src/backup.c#L344-L351). Also note that trace callback is invoked *before* the command is actually executed. That's why `backup` is executed in transaction. Ideally you should move call to `backup` after execution of `COMMIT`.

Comment: Another point is that the [documentation of `backup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.backup) is not completely honest with you. Backup operation will be blocked by any pending write locks on the database unless you use [WAL mode](http://www3.sqlite.org/wal.html). If you perform backup in multiple steps (i.e. you use `pages` argument) and database is modified in between the steps, then backup operation is restarted.